# jquery and ajax send json data to server

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I want to send json data to server by ajax but it doesnt work. test with firefox and chrome browser . interactive with Tornado

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: json_data
});
```

but if I add success property inside . it works. I dont understand the reason

working version:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: json_data,
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);    
    }
});
```

then,
I replace the success with complete. it doesnt work again.
why?

```
complete: function(xmlHttp){
    if(xmlHttp.status.toString()[0]=='3'){
        top.location.href = xmlHttp.getResponseHeader('Location');}
```

let me know if you need more information.
Thanks

Comment: looks like you have an extra `}` in your first script - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/er3b7ufr/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/er3b7ufr/2/

Comment: I remove the extra } , but it doesnt work

Comment: @Arun, Your link works for me. I found on the complete version, I have syntax error. but I still dont understand why I the first version doesnt work.

Comment: I try again. I think it is syntax error on my code. thanks for Arun.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Post your data from JSON like this

```js
var myvalue = 'test';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/echo/json/",
    data: {getval: myvalue},
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Successfully posted");

    }
       
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Jsfiddle demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/6d688qah/)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your problem might stem from how you are determining success.

I took your code and put it in the following [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/er3b7ufr/3/) and was able to post to their echo service without issues:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/echo/json/",
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: {a: "test"},
    success: function ( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        alert("Succeeded with status: " +textStatus+". Data returned: "+data);

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Failed with status: "+textStatus+", errorThrown: "+errorThrown);

    },
    complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("Completed with status: "+textStatus);

    }
});
```

Comment: "complete" is deprecated - use "always".  "success" should be replaced by "done"

Comment: @brunofitas you seem to be mixing up the success/error/complete callbacks with jqXHR.done/jqXHR.success/jqXHR.always/jqXHR.complete, the former of which is not deprecated.